# Why is there $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|\sin(n\theta_0)|\geq c > 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, real-numbers

I'm trying to show that the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{|\sin(n\theta_0)|}{n},$$

diverges, where $0 < \theta_0 < \pi$. One suggestion given in the text I'm reading is to show that "for many values of $n$ we have $|\sin(n\theta_0)|\geq c>0$.

Now, I can't see why that's true. Of course $0 < |\sin(n\theta_0)|\leq 1$, thus we need to show that $|\sin(n\theta_0)|$ is actually greater than zero.

But if we pick $n = 2$, for instance we have $0 < 2\theta_0 < 2\pi$, so that it could be the case that $2\theta_0 = \pi$ and the sine is zero.

The same seems to happen almost always, for $n = 3$, $0 < 3\theta_0 < 3\pi$ and inside this interval lies $\pi, 2\pi$, and so forth.

My initial idea was to pick $c_n$ a number on the interval $[0,\sin(n\theta_0)]$ and define $c = \inf\{c_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Obviously each $c_n\leq \sin(n\theta_0)$, so that $c\leq \sin(n\theta_0)$. It would remain to show that $c\neq 0$.

But this doesn't work. If for some $n$, $\sin(n\theta_0)$ is zero, $c_n$ would necessarily be zero, and $c$ would also be zero, and the minimum of that set.

In that case, how can I show that $|\sin(n\theta_0)|\geq c > 0$?

Comment: @SimpleArt But $1+\frac13+\frac15+\frac17+\ldots$ diverges!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh, my bad.  I did not see the absolute bars

Answer (score 2):

You are not asked to show that $|\sin(n\theta_0)|\ge c$ for *all* $n$, but only for (sufficiently) *many* $n$.
Remarkably, you can easily show that it cannot happen that two consecutive values $|\sin(n\theta_0)|$, $|\sin((n+1)\theta_0)|$ are small. At least one of these two must be $\ge \sin \delta$, if $2\delta\le \theta_0\le\pi-2\delta$.